# Name of movie involving time travel with a ruby ring?

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, history

I'm looking for the name of a movie that aired on TV I think in the early 2000's. From what I remember of the plot it involved a young woman who traveled back in time (i think to the 1800's) by a ruby ring and ends up entering a mansion from behind a painting. A romance develops between her and I think the Lord of the mansion. I don't remember much more except at the end she was riding on a black horse in a yellow dress.  I'd really like to know the name of this movie and if it is also a book. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It's called "[The Ruby Ring](http://Www.imdb.com/title/tt0134942/)" (TV 1997)

> *A teenage girl named Lucy receives a ruby ring from her grandmother and it has a dramatic history and the power to grant two wishes within 24 hours. When Lucy wishes to live in a "much larger house," she's magically transported to a nearby castle in a time long past, 1885.*

As you can see from the screenshot (and trailer) below, there's a scene involving a horse-ride in a yellow dress.

[image: Ruby Ring]

Comment: there is also a movie Ruby red https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9r4u5_ReCw

Comment: I've been looking for the film for the past 5 years, does anyone know where I can see the film online?

Comment: @zecy - You can view it on the showtime website. Next airing is on Wednesday; http://www.sho.com/sho/movies/titles/101035/the-ruby-ring#/airings/101035/the-ruby-ring#