# '80s or '90s movie about a cop who travels back in time when he puts on a ring taken from a creature he was following

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I'm looking for the name of a movie that released in the '80s or '90s. From what I remember of the plot, it involved a young man who is a cop who travelled back in time (I think to the 1800s) by putting on a ring from a creature he was following. That creature from the past wreaked havoc in the cop's time. The only dialogue I remember is: "You have been ripped from your reality."

Comment: So he didn't inhabit the body of one of his ancestors?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trancers? Not 1800s though.

Comment: {nods} But that's the closest I've found so far.

Comment: :) Ring and 1800s at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56359/name-of-movie-involving-time-travel-with-a-ruby-ring?rq=1, but no killer or cop.

Comment: Timecop went back to the 1800s. No rings or monsters.

Answer (score 16):

I think this might be ***[Nostradamus](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0207631/?ref_=tt_urv)*** (2000).

> Rob Estes plays a homicide detective investigating a series of strange multiple murders, assisted by an oddball FBI agent, played by Joely Fisher, who is also clairvoyant. The apparent perpetrator is a time travelling assassin, come all the way from the 15th century seeking to bring about Armageddon.

An all-male cult of devil worshippers in 16th century France use a time machine to send an assassin to modern day Minneapolis. His mission is to kill every person named on a list he's brought with him, which will supposedly bring about the apocalypse. He wears a special ring that allows him to return to the 16th century at certain times, apparently dictated by the alignment of the stars.

Most of the men in the cult look normal, but the assassin is odd-looking, which might explain why you described him as a "creature". He has long red hair, red irises, and long, almost claw-like fingernails. He also never speaks, except when he's about to kill one of his targets. In that case, he chants some sort of spell in Latin, which apparently erases the victim's soul from existence, and causes their body to spontaneously combust. His irises turn an unnatural shade of light blue when he's casting this spell. He's also kept gagged when he's in his own time, presumably because of his ability to kill people with a few words.

The murders he commits in Minneapolis get him on the radar of a pair of homicide detectives. One of them eventually manages to kill him with a bullet to the head. Later, back at the police station, this detective takes the killer's ring out of an evidence bag, puts it on, and is transported back to 16th century France. One of the people he meets there tells him that his *"system's still in shock, adjusting to the new realities"*, and also says that *"when the machine brought you here, it erased you from your time."*

I won't reveal any more of the plot, since this is enough to cover everything in your description, but you can watch the whole film in the video below, and the specific scene where the detective puts the ring on and is transported back in time occurs at the 45:20 mark.

Comment: @Vashisht Raghav - If anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.